# How do you stop Javascript, Jquery from running when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

My code is binding the singletap, doubletap event to links inside of my projects div.

I need to make it so that whenever an a element is clicked inside of my projects div that these events do not not occur however I still need the a elements to function as normal links.

I've tried using return false inside of functions that are called whenever an a element is clicked but that doesn't work.  How can I make this happen?

Edit: Still having the same issue.

I still need the links to work so `event.preventDefault()` isn't an option.

```
var projects = document.getElementById('projects');
var hammerTime = new Hammer.Manager(projects);
hammerTime.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 }));
hammerTime.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'singletap' }));
hammerTime.get('doubletap').recognizeWith('singletap');
// we only want to trigger a tap, when we don't have detected a doubletap
hammerTime.get('singletap').requireFailure('doubletap');
hammerTime.on("singletap", function(ev)
{
    $('.navCharacter').fadeOut(2000);
});
hammerTime.on("doubletap", function(ev) {});
```

Comment: can you provide it in more details..?

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what the problem is. Please describe what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`event.preventDefault();`

check [the api](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

e.g.,

```
hammerTime.on("singletap", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('.navCharacter').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `e.stopPropagation`. This function stop the propagation of the events when you click.

```
hammerTime.on("singletap", function(ev)
{
    $('.navCharacter').fadeOut(2000)
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```